# iOS -swift 6.4-tableview

Tags: ios, swift

what's the wrong there is a thread appears next to class AppDelegate how can deal with it can someone help me !

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var childTable:UITableView!
    var names = [String]()

    @IBAction func addChild(sender: AnyObject) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Name",
            message: "Add a new name",
            preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",
            style: .Default,
            handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in

                let textField = alert.textFields!.first
                self.names.append(textField!.text!)
                self.childTable.reloadData()
        })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel",
            style: .Default) { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        }

        alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler {
            (textField: UITextField) -> Void in
        }

        alert.addAction(saveAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)

        presentViewController(alert,
            animated: true,
            completion: nil)

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "\"The List\""
        childTable.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self,
            forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




    //UITableViewDataSource
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

        return names.count
    }
    //bulding cell
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let cell = childTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")

        cell!.textLabel!.text = names[indexPath.row]

        return cell!

    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you getting an exception or error message?  What is the message?

Comment: set up a breakpoint and step through your program, also, look in your console window for an error and share it here.

Comment: I get an exception in run time the simulator screen become black